# how to customize user profile page

Tags: theming, users

I want to customize user profile page as per my own way.
I have created one file named as page--user.tpl.php, but after making changes in this file during user logged in, the changes reflects on sign up(register page) without logged in.
But i only wants to change the look and feel of individual user's page.

Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly do you want to change? General page template when you are on that page OR user profile form OR user profile display?

Answer (score 1):

You've simply used the wrong template. page--user.tpl.php affects "user pages" like, as you've discovered, the user login.

The template you want to create and modify is **user-profile.tpl.php** https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7

Comment: I have made changes in page--user-profile.tpl.php , but this file does not reflecting any changes as reflecting by creating page--user.tpl.php, but i don't want to change my register page

Comment: If you actually want to edit content in the page template, not the content area which is what user-profile.tpl.php will do, you either need to write a preprocess function for your theme or you can do what is suggested here http://www.trevorsimonton.com/blog/page-usertplphp-profile-php-template-drupal

The example is for Drupal 6, not 7 so the template names are off for example page--user.tpl.php is the D7 implementation.